# Capture the Selected Text from ms word file and save it to XBRL file

Tags: ms-word, xbrl, interstage

I have to Create XBRL file from the MS word file which contains different reports in text format.
Need to Select and save it as tag value in XBRL file 
in respective tag
is there any way to do it

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking if there is commercial or open source software that turns Word content into XBRL, then the answer is "of course". You can just search your favorite search engine for "Word to XBRL" and will see a wide variety of products, such as Fujitsu's XWand Word Tagger (http://www.fujitsu.com/global/services/software/interstage/solutions/xbrl/). Depending on your programming acumen, there's a number of open source tools and APIs, which you can find on SourceForge and related sites.

You don't specify the filing regime and whether you only care about creating the instance document or whether you will need to develop a company-specific extension taxonomy as wel; that may complicate your situation.